# Omaha Poker: 3 of a kind using only 1 card

Tags: omaha, 3-of-a-kind

A game of Omaha poker where each player is dealt 4 cards and must use exactly 2 hole cards at shown down.

The table shows the following cards;
A 3 3 K Q

Player 1 has: 3 7 5 2
Can player 1 claim he has a 3 of a kind if the game is Omaha.

Comment: Omaha is any 2 cards in your hand with any 3 on the board. player one has 33357 as his best hand

Comment: Actually, 3-3-3-A-7.  3-7 from his hand and 3-3-A from the board.